# Key Fragment chance reset rate

Tags: league-of-legends

AFAIK the chances for a player to get a key fragment decreases as soon as he/she gets each key fragment. How and when does it reset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wingfield, a Riot enployee,

> Hey all,
>
> Just want to help clarify some things about key drop rates:
>
> Key drop rates are NOT linear and only wins have a chance of dropping
>   a key. So you will earn key fragments much faster in your earlier wins
>   than you will in your later wins. Or said another way, each
>   incremental key fragment drop is harder than the last (on average...
>   there is variance). This resets on a monthly basis for each player
>   individually. The goal is to create a nice ebb and flow.
>
> Grade does NOT impact key drop chance.
>
> Premades DO increase drop chance.
>
> Chests earned has no impact on key drop chance.
>
> There is variance and randomness (with limits). It's unlikely that
>   what happened to your friend will happen to you.
>
> Hope that helps clarify :)

[source](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bug-report/rJ4rQmHA-after-getting-4-chests-key-fragments-no-longer-seem-to-drop-for-a-lot-of-people?comment=0006)

Answer (score -1):

The big issue with the key drops that the communitie, was that people had a very low chance of getting one after wins. However, after the recent patches (6.8-6.9) the chance of getting a key shard has increased and is now available when winning a aram as well. (still have to win)